# Oscilloscope and probes

Tags: oscilloscope

What effect , if any, has using a x10 probe on:

1. Voltage reading of oscilloscope with resistance box set to zero ohm?
2. Voltage reading of oscilloscope with the resistance box set to 900k Ohm?
3. And what can you infer from above on what has happened to the internal resistance of oscilloscope now you have x10 probe in series with it?

[image]

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question. We expect you to do a significant amount of work on your own homework and then ask a very specific question. What have you tried to do to solve this yourself? What **do** you know about the issues in the question?

Comment: What resistance box?  Do you have a schematic?

Comment: @TimWescott resistance decade box, 1MOhm

Comment: What have you come up with?  What do **you** think the answers should be?  What causes you to doubt your answers so much that you asked for help?

Comment: Since this is voltage divider circuit, output voltage should go towards the lower resistance. So for first one i guess no  effect, for second and third not sure

Answer (score 1):

\$Vo/Vi = 10M/(10M+0.5M+50)= 0.95237\$
\$Vo/Vi = 10M/(10M+0.9M+50)= 0.91743\$

Load error is the impedance ratio of load to total series impedance as the same current with a voltage divider.

The same is true for power supplies called Load regulation error.

Is a supply has 1% series Rs of rated Vo/Io=RL load, then load regulation error is RL/(RL+Rs). So if Load reg error =1% then Rload must be 99 x Rs.

If both are equal then you get 50% drop in voltage.

In your case if you wanted 1% error ***without load correction***, your probe must be 99x900k= ~ 90Meg

The easy way to measure an unknown R is to match its series with a known R load to get 50%V for high value R's. This is called a **bridge method.**

Comment: No need to calculate anything, could you explain in words?